# how can i fetch the tr of this structure in nokogiri of in html response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri

how can i fetch the tr which mention in code of this structure in nokogiri of in html response

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table>

    </table>

  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <table>
            <tr></tr>
              <tr><td> wanna this text as output.</td></tr>
          </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: table structure is not valid.

Comment: Please check here SE before posting the question.. and make sure the questions are very cleared with proper data..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using the CSS accessors as they're more forgiving. Using your HTML sample, I'd use:

```
irb(main):026:0> doc.search('table table tr').last.text
" wanna this text as output."
```

Alternately, the XPATH accessor is:

```
irb(main):042:0> doc.search('//table//table//tr').last.text
" wanna this text as output."
```

You're looking for the nested table containing multiple rows. You want the last row.

Be wary whenever you look at the HTML inside a browser and see a `<table><tbody>` combination. Browsers do a lot of code fix-up, which can result in tags that are not there when you retrieve the HTML directly and pass it into a parser. And, those non-existing tags you see in the browser's output will throw off your CSS or XPath access when you add them in. In particular, `<tbody>` is a real common problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to access that text, for instance:

```
html = Nokogiri::HTML my_html_string
row_text = html.at('//table[2]/tbody/tr/td/table/tr[2]').text
```

Comment: This one is not working for me

Comment: That's because your actual HTML is different.